# Dividing a set of n elements into k disjoint subsets.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, permutations, combinations

I have been able to do the 1st part.
I have not been able to prove the 2nd part.

My attempt to the solution :- I took $k$ groups $ a_1, a_2, a_3…, a_k $
 Let $a_1$ group has $b_1$ similarly so on..where $b_1+ b_2+…+b_k = n$

Hence it would be  ncb1 + ncb2 + ... ncbk (here c stands for combinatorics coeffecient)

But couldn't solve it from here.
Please help !

[image]

Comment: why are u all down voting it..i have given my attempt also.? What is missing??

Comment: What do you mean by "ncbk"?  Things could be expressed more clearly.

Comment: Perhaps people are down-voting the question because the title is not informative, it uses excess punctuation ("!!!!") and deliberately poor spelling ("plz"), it includes an image which could have easily been retyped instead, and it does not use MathJax for its equations.  Moreover, as John M said, it is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Start with $n$ elements, then add one more element to get $k$ classes.  What are the possibilities?

Comment: thnx..!! now i have been able to solve it.